# Disabling UINavigationItem custom right view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I create a custom right view as follows:

```
// Build the Segmented Control
NSArray *segmentTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-dice.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-up.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-down.png"], nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTextContent];

// Customize the Segmented Control
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then I add it to my navigation bar as follows:

```
// Add the control to the navigation bar right item
UIBarButtonItem *segmentItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"";
[segmentItem release];
```

I can hide it as follows:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.hidden = NO;
```

QUESTION
...but how can I disable all (or better, a specific element) of the segmented control?

The following does not work.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Any ideas appreciated...

Thanks,
matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UISegmentedControl.h

```
- (void)removeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)removeAllSegments;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment;       //default is YES

  e.g. [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Hope That helps

Comment: Thank you, I'd missed that in the docs.

Is there an easier way to disable the whole control rather than doing this for each segment in turn?

Comment: It's a subclass of UIControl, so you should be able to simply do segmentedControl.enabled = NO;. In the code you presented above, you would add “.customView” after “rightBarButtonItem” and before “.enabled”.

Comment: That didn't work for me, sadly. Enabled is not a valid property of CustomView.

Answer (score 0):

```
[navItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

as simple as that :)

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html
See the **enabled** property.

Comment: This only works for the first element e.g. rightBarButtonItem. If you have more items in an array "rightBarButtonItems" than you have to disable each item manually. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20013762/384864