# Disabling RightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, objective-c

My viewController is functioning as a container and has its own UINavigationBar.  It is not in a naviagtion controller.  My nav bar items are set up like so...

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftItems;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[logout, settings];
[self.navBar setItems:@[self.navigationItem]];
```

At various points in the application this navigation bar is locked down until the user completes a task.  This snippet works fine for toggling the enabled property of the buttons in the navigation bar but only on the leftBarButtonItems!  Why?

```
for(UIBarButtonItem *rightButton in self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems){
     [rightButton setEnabled:!rightButton.enabled];
}
for(UIBarButtonItem *leftButton in self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems){
     [leftButton setEnabled:!leftButton.enabled];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I just tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you have multiple right bar button items?  Or is it just a single item?

Comment: @HalR - it's multiple.  Question updated.

Comment: @0x7fffffff - Have a look at my updated question.

Comment: I have updated my answer for updated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I had created a test demo, it works well. Here is the sreenshots and code, hope to give you some help!

[image]
[image]

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong) UINavigationItem * navItem;
@property(nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet UINavigationBar * navBar;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem* barItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(barItemClicked:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* barItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(barItemClicked:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* barItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(barItemClicked:)];
    UIBarButtonItem* barItem4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(barItemClicked:)];
    self.navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    self.navItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barItem1,barItem2];
    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[barItem3,barItem4];
    [self.navBar setItems:@[self.navItem]];

}
- (IBAction)anableSwitch:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl * swith = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    for(UIBarButtonItem *rightButton in self.navItem.leftBarButtonItems){
        [rightButton setEnabled:(swith.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)];
    }
    for(UIBarButtonItem *leftButton in self.navItem.rightBarButtonItems){
        [leftButton setEnabled:(swith.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)];
    }
}
- (void)barItemClicked:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"barItemClicked");
}
```

Comment: I've updated my code and the question realizing my approach was a little strange, but the end result is still the same.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using a navItem property like you did made the difference.  Thanks!